# Importing a bundles routes causes redirects if pattern is /

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

**app/config/routing.yml**

```
NelmioApiDocBundle:
resource: "@NelmioApiDocBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /api/doc
```

**vendor/nelmio/api-doc-bundle/Nelmio/ApiDocBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml**

```
nelmio_api_doc_index:
    pattern: /
    defaults: { _controller: NelmioApiDocBundle:ApiDoc:index }
    requirements:
        _method: GET
```

The above setup ends in a redirect loop when visiting mydomain.com/api/doc

If I add anything onto the pattern in the imported route, i.e. `pattern: /test` the page loads as expected.

Comment: What other routes do you have configured and did you enable the bundle's config?

Comment: I've got a bunch of other routes, even if I delete them all I still get the same issue, so I'm rulling that out. I enabled the bundles config by doing this in app/config.yml `# Nemio API Auto Doc
nelmio_api_doc: ~`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by my .htaccess file trying to remove the trailing slash, hence causing the redirect loop.

```
#remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```